# Azure B2C Tenant and Graph API, user management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

This is regarding an application where we are using Azure B2C tenant for authentication. There is a requirement to get lists of users which would support filtering, pagination and users have to be from a particular TenantId.  We are using Graph API SDK that i.e., microsoft.graph and microsoft.graph.Auth packages.

Steps I have done

1. Created graph client with ClientCredentialProvider with TenantId.
2. Getting users using the below code

```cs
var users = await graphClient.Users
.Request()
.Top(100)
.Filter("identities/any(c:c/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com')")
.Select("displayName,id,identities")
.GetAsync();
```

This gets all users for a given issuer or tenant.  Now, there is an issue I cannot filter users using this option `.Filter("identities/any(c:c/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com') and startswith(displayName,'a')` i.e., get all users whose display name starts with 'a' and belong to this issuer 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com'.  As per Microsoft, Graph API does not currently support complex queries on Identities. They show this message `Message: Complex query on property identities is not supported.`

Now, right now my thoughts are limited to this option of loading entire user table for this tenant onto memory.  I think this would be not the best approach, because we will have more tenants and I don't know how much users we can store in memory.

Anyone who has more understanding on these type of scenarios, please share your inputs.  I wanted to know various other alternatives we could take.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, *"Complex query on property identities is not supported"*, it's also not supported in Microsoft Graph SDK. You could only check the users with [String.StartsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0) method in C#.

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Top(100)
    .Filter("identities/any(c:c/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com')")
    .Select("displayName,id,identities")
    .GetAsync();

List<User> userResult = new List<User>();
foreach(var user in users)
{
     
    if (user.displayName.StartsWith(a)) {
         
        userResult.add(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: This filtering with StartsWith approach we can do it.  I was more concerned about improving the performance on retrieving and storing the users list.  Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: If you have enough users that this takes a large amount of time, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871948/c-sharp-list-add-method-performance) shows you performance of adding List and another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach) to improve the loop. It's better to raise a question in C# and performance tags.

Comment: Thanks for the help and response Pamela.  I will evaluate it and see how it works.